# Optimizing a two-level SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's the layout of the relevant parts of my database:

[image: database design]

(BTW, I made this diagram with [wwwsqldesigner](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/))

Now, I like to query all rows of C which match a particular row of A.

The query I came up with myself works. E.g, to look up rows in C matching A's row 123:

```
SELECT C.* FROM C
LEFT JOIN B1 ON (B1.id = C.id_B1)
LEFT JOIN B2 ON (B2.id = C.id_B2)
WHERE B1.id_A = 123 OR B2.id_A = 123
```

However, I believe the above query is rather inefficient as it collects all rows of B1 and B2 in a large set before reducing it down again, right?

I believe I should be able to first make a query for B1 and B2 each, selecting for their id_A values, then joins those results somehow into the matching C rows.

I've looked at [sqlite.org's docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for the SELECT command but the possibilities overwhelm me.

How does one figure this out? A bit of explaining the thought process of solving this would be appreciated.

(Also, if you could suggest a better title for this question - I don't really know how to pinpoint this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is fine, although it seems like it might be returning duplicates.

You might see if one of these is faster:

```
SELECT  C.*
FROM C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B1 WHERE B1.id = C.id_B1 AND B1.id_A = 123) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B2 WHERE B2.id = C.id_B2 AND B2.id_A = 123);
```

This will work best with indexes.  An index on `id` in the "B" tables is fine, although `(id, id_A)` would be better.

OR:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.*
FROM C JOIN
     B1 ON B1.id = C.id_B1
WHERE B1.id_A = 123 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT C.*
FROM C JOIN
     B2 ON B1.id = C.id_B2
WHERE B2.id_A = 123;
```

If you know there are no duplicates, then use `union all` instead of `union`.

Comment: Ah yes, I have added a `GROUP BY C.id` at the end of my query for that. I found that I could also avoid dupes by using "SELECT DISTINCT C.*" but it appears that that's slower that the GROUP BY way. Thanks for the two examples. The UNION is helpful but I think the first example is best. I will add indexes as well eventually. Still, I like to first learn how to get these queries right.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the above query is rather inefficient as it collects all rows of B1 and B2 in a large set before reducing it down again, right?

I may be wrong for SQLite, but any database engine worth its salt should be able to optimize the query by finding the rows in `B1` and `B2` that match your `where` clause, so no, it would not load the entire tables into memory.

You can see the plan that the query uses by prefacing the query with [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).  As long as the engine doesn't do a SCAN TABLE on `B1` and/or `B2` then the query should be fine.

Note that you can improve the performance of *this query* dramatically by adding indexes on `B1.id_A` and `B2.id_A`

Comment: The "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" hint is great. That helps me at least to verify whether I'm efficient or not. If it's inefficient, I'll still have to ask here for help for now, though :)

Comment: When I read the sqlite docs for the SELECT command correctly, then the WHERE part gets only processed after performing the JOINs. I also got the impression that the query takes rather long with this construct.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann I'm not a SQLite expert by any means so I can't speak to that.  However I would be surprised if the engine loaded up all data into memory (which is what you are implying) before filtering.  I suspect it uses indexes or other means to load only the necessary data.